# How to  reach the first view from any view in a navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

How to reach the first view of the navigation controller from any of the loaded views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

That will pop all view controllers down to the root. If the main menu is not your root view controller then you can use this:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:mainMenuVC animated:YES];
```

In this case you need to have a "pointer" to the mainMenuVC available. You can do that by setting a property in the App Delegate.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following UINavigationController method when the back button is tapped:

```
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```